# Stripe Payment using saved credit card

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I use following code to save credit card in stripe.

```
string stripeKey = "";

var guid = Guid.Parse(userGuid);
var systemUser = _systemUserRepository.Get(a => a.UserGuid == guid).FirstOrDefault();
var accountProfile = _accountProfileRepository.Get(a => a.SystemUser == systemUser.ID).FirstOrDefault();
var customer = _clientRepository.Get(a => a.AccountProfile == accountProfile.ID).FirstOrDefault();

var myCustomer = new StripeCustomerCreateOptions();
myCustomer.Email = customer.AccountProfile1.SystemUser1.Email;
myCustomer.Description = customer.AccountProfile1.FirstName + " " + customer.AccountProfile1.LastName;

var customerService = new StripeCustomerService(stripeKey);
StripeCustomer stripeCustomer = customerService.Create(myCustomer);

var myCard = new StripeCardCreateOptions();

// setting up the card
myCard.SourceCard = new SourceCard
{
    Number = cardNumber,
    ExpirationYear = expireYear,
    ExpirationMonth = expireMonth,
};

var cardService = new StripeCardService(stripeKey);
StripeCard stripeCard = cardService.Create(stripeCustomer.Id, myCard);
```

How can I make a payment using this saved credit card(StripeCard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the card is saved properly, you can charge it using the Create Charge [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) and passing the customer id `cus_XXXX` in the `customer` parameter and the card id `card_YYYy` in the `source` parameter. With Stripe.net, the code is documented [here](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#creating-a-charge) and would look like this:

```
var myCharge = new StripeChargeCreateOptions();
myCharge.Amount = 5153;
myCharge.Currency = "usd";
myCharge.SourceTokenOrExistingSourceId = stripeCard.Id;
myCharge.CustomerId = stripeCustomer.Id;

var chargeService = new StripeChargeService();
StripeCharge stripeCharge = chargeService.Create(myCharge);
```

It's also important to note that your current code is sending card details through the API directly. This means that you get the card numbers on your server. This is a bad idea and breaks [PCI compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/). You should really modify your integration and always tokenize the card details first client-side.

You should use [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) or [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) client-side to send the card details to Stripe directly and get a unique card token (tok_XXX) that you'd then send safely to your server to create the customer.